# VC++ - application crashed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I've some problem with VC++ 2010. What i do:

- create new project (Windows Form Application)
- start debugging (F5)
- copy .exe from Debug folder
- run it in 3 computers with XP - all is ok.

Next:

- add to to Form1.h: #include (under '#pragma once' comment) - and nothing else
- start debugging
- copy .exe from Debug folder
- run it in 3 computers with XP - it runs only on one.

Net Framework 4 is installed on every pc.

Errors when crashed:

- ModName: kernel32.dll      ModVer: 5.1.2600.3541      ModStamp:49c4f7e4
- fDebug: 0       Offset: 00012a6b

What could be wrong?

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Instead of copying .exe from Debug folder, compile your project as **Release** and not as **Debug**. Thus, you can use .exe from Release folder on others Pc without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if VC 2010 Redistributables are installed on system on which it is crashing

Comment: Thanks! This is it :) You save my day! Sorry, Im low reputation and cant thick Your answer as useful :(

Comment: Earn reputation and check your answer :)